# String value to PrepareStatement for TimeStamp comparasion

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, timestamp

SELECT data from table using WHERE clause for TimeStamp.
I would like to set a String value retrived from TextField to show filtered table.

### NOT WORKING:

```
public ResultSet queryAlarms() throws SQLException
String sql = "SELECT * FROM BDCS.dbo.Alarms WHERE AlarmTime > ?";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, " '2017-12-29 14:45' ");
return ps.executeQuery();
}
```

### WORKING:

```
public ResultSet queryAlarms() throws SQLException {
String sql = "SELECT * FROM BDCS.dbo.Alarms WHERE AlarmTime > '2017-12-29 14:45'";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
return ps.executeQuery();
}
```

Does someone know how to sent a value properly? Or what could be better way for this?

Comment: Rather than a `String` pass either a `LocalDateTime` or an `Instant` to the query. `ps.setObject(1, myLocalDateTime);` or similarly for an instant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..!

```
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1,getCurrentTimeStamp());
```

You can use text-field string to generate the timestamp as well.

```
private static java.sql.Timestamp getCurrentTimeStamp() {

    java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
    return new java.sql.Timestamp(today.getTime());

}


private static Timestamp getTimeStamp(String ts){

 //Change the format as per your requirement
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  Date date = dateFormat.parse(ts));
  long time = date.getTime();
  new Timestamp(time);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for you investigation! Your solution could not work from me - i will investigate it leater :) However I did a simple casting bt Timestamp.valueOf(String)

Comment: A `Timestamp` object is a step forward compared to `String`. However, that class is very long outmoded, so why not take *two* steps forward and use a modern class? Either `LocalDateTime` or `Instant`, both from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.

Comment: `Timestamp`s are setted in the db. It's temporary solution to have a look for db directly from desktop. All in all, your prompt sound rly good. ;)

Comment: In spite of the name being the same, a `Timestamp` in Java is not the same thing as a `timestamp`in SQL. Not knowing the SQL Server JDBC driver, it should be possible to pass `Instant` or `LocalDateTime` to `setObject` and get an SQL `timestamp` on the database side.